# How to get the soap envelope with suds python

Tags: python, wsdl, suds

How can I get the soap envelope,and how can I change the values before sending to server.

ex: Soap envelope

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"    
xmlns:ws="http://www.altoromutual.com/bank/ws/">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
  <ws:TransferBalance>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ws:transDetails>
        <ws:transferDate>2013-01-01T00:00:00</ws:transferDate>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ws:debitAccount>1001160141</ws:debitAccount>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ws:creditAccount>1001160140</ws:creditAccount>
        <ws:transferAmount>2.0</ws:transferAmount>
     </ws:transDetails>
  </ws:TransferBalance>
```

I want to hold this envelope and change the values before sending to server.How can I do it with suds

Thanks

Comment: You can use the [Doctors](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#Doctors) class depending on how you want to change it. Or you can download and modify the wsdl that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, you don't necessarily need to use suds to modify the envelope. Instead you can save the request as a template, use your favorite templating engine to change any values you need to change, and pass the whole request to the suds call using the `__inject` parameter.

Here's a simple example:

```
import suds
from mako.template import Template

WSDL = 'https://example.com/someservice?wsdl'

client = suds.client.Client(WSDL)
template = Template(filename='template.xml')
request = template.render(debitaccount='someaccount', creditaccount='anotheraccount')
response = client.service.some_call(__inject={'msg':request})
```

And the template

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"    
xmlns:ws="http://www.altoromutual.com/bank/ws/">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
  <ws:TransferBalance>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ws:transDetails>
        <ws:transferDate>2013-01-01T00:00:00</ws:transferDate>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ws:debitAccount>${debitaccount}</ws:debitAccount>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ws:creditAccount>${creditaccount}</ws:creditAccount>
        <ws:transferAmount>2.0</ws:transferAmount>
     </ws:transDetails>
  </ws:TransferBalance>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Pls suggest some templating engine. I am new to webservices and suds.If you have some sample code that would help